# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: GetOrdersProvider <- GetOrders <- OrderController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to do get post actions on different URLs. When I tried to write different factories I guess it could recogine the other factory.

Service.js

```
var app = angular.module("ServiceApp", ["ngResource"]);

    app.factory('GetPortfolios', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolios/", {}, {
    });

    app.factory('GetOrders', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolioOrders/");
    });
});
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module("UiApp", ["ServiceApp"]);

app.controller("PortFolioController", function ($scope, GetPortfolios) {
    $scope.Portfolios = GetPortfolios.query({ pmid: 2 });
    console.log($scope.Portfolios);
});

app.controller("OrderController", function ($scope, GetOrders) {
    $scope.Orders = GetOrders.query({ id: 25 });
    console.log(Orders);
});
```

Comment: both the factory are missing `});` closing brackets of factory functions

Comment: @PankajParkar I think only the first one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Service.js, first factory is missing the closing **`})`** paranthesis, check the updated Service.js

```
var app = angular.module("ServiceApp", ["ngResource"]);

app.factory('GetPortfolios', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolios/", {}, {});
});

app.factory('GetOrders', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolioOrders/");
});
```